# Ionic 5 : How to navigate to the child and to the sub-child

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, angular8, ionic5

I try to migrate my app written with ionic 3 to ionic 5.
This is a nightmare !
In my app, I have the following case:
[image]

The 2 arrows show when I touch the top right button this is excecute `router.navigate()` the Page1 appear with his back-button. But when I touch the top right button of Page1, the `router.navigate()` is executed from Page1, the Page2 appear **without back-button**.
In Page1 and Page2 I use `<ion-back-button></ion-back-button>`
I don't know how **to reveal the back-button on the Page2**. I think there is a problem with Routes configurations, but I don't know to solve it...
I created a new app from scratch with ionic CLI :

```
> ionic start tabs myApp
```

And I added the 2 pages with :

```
> ionic generate page Page1
```

And same for the Page2.

app-routing.module.ts :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'page1',
    loadChildren: () => import('./page1/page1.module').then( m => m.Page1PageModule)
  },

  {
    path: 'page2',
    loadChildren: () => import('./page2/page2.module').then( m => m.Page2PageModule)
  }
];
```

page1-routing.module.ts :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Page1
  }
];
```

Thanks.

Comment: could you show your route definitions as well as your calls to `router.navigate()`?

Comment: The template header would be fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem :

I moved Page2 route from `app-routing.module.ts` to `page1-routing.module.ts`
In the `page1.page.ts` I call Page2 from Page1 :

```
this.router.navigate(['Page1', 'Page2']
```

app-routing.module.ts :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'page1',
    loadChildren: () => import('./page1/page1.module').then( m => m.Page1PageModule)
  }
];
```

page1-routing.module.ts :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Page1
  },
  {
    path: 'page2',
    loadChildren: () => import('./page2/page2.module').then( m => m.Page2PageModule)
  }
];
```

The back button appear and work fine.